# Is it possible to obtain a MAC address in Silverlight / ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-3.0

As the topic says - for the purpose of maintaining a session state, I'm debating whether it is - or not - possible to obtain a MAC address of a network card of the machine that's connecting to the website ?

What are any other machine specific - values that can be obtained for the purpose of identifying an individual machine ?

Comment: Loved the original 'Slivelright' spelling :)

Comment: Thats weird, I don't see an edit. Was the original deleted?

Comment: Let's say that I was kinda "tired" while I was writing it lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ASP.NET you can't find the MAC address of the request. The best thing you can do is generate a guid and send it as a cookie if it doesn't exist yet.